# Windows Command Prompt Change

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm trying to follow [this](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-node-webkit-apps/) tutorial and part of it involves working in the Windows Command Prompt.  I'm running Windows 7 on a 64 bit machine and running cmd.exe as an administrator.  The issue is this line:

```
../nw/nw.exe app.nw
```

The file/folder dependency is like this:

```
myNodeWebkitApps
    helloWorld
    nw
```

Where `nw.exe` is located in folder `nw` and I am executing the line of code from hellowWorld.  app.nw is located in the helloWorld folder. The error I recieve is `'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.  Any thoughts on how to execute this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `..\nw\nw.exe app.nw` (inverted slash, which is the Windows standard path separator).

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  Will approve as checked once the time limit is up